# Apache HTTPD Config Visualization

Tags: apache, graphics, visualization

Does anyone know of a tool that shows a visualization of an Apache HTTPD server configuration? I'm looking for something that I can run against a DMZ server that does a lot of ReverseProxy mapping. I have inherited 3 Apache servers that have ~100 VirtualHosts. It would be nice to be able to see for each VHOST what the specific configuration setting apply to each one.  Where are the Error pages coming from for the host, locally globally or from the DMZ server? Things like HTTP Trace method that I cannot seem to turn off (despite the use of TraceEnable and Rewrite rules)

Are there any higher level tools for managing Apache configurations, dependencies and visualizing the relationships between servers?

Any/all replies appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at http://www.apache-gui.com/  might be useful?

Comment: Pretty much exactly what I was looking for!